# Account suspended?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I've been using stackoverflow and was up to 31 reputation. Suddenly it decreased to 1 and my profile shows the following message:

> This account is temporarily suspended. The suspension period ends on May 6 at 8:01.

Why was I suspended? How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't you get any msg in your inbox about why your account is suspended?

Comment: Or, a [top bar notification](http://i.imgur.com/tDuP0.png) for a [private moderator message](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/)?

Answer (score 11):

Suspended by Jeff Atwood.  Annotation notes the lack of quality in questions.  User has also collected a large number of flags since joining:

---

*asked 5 hours ago*
0bluetooth programming
**low quality – 5 hours ago**
♦ Post Deleted

*asked Mar 24 at 7:32*
0 windows embedded installation [closed]
**off topic; belongs on Super User – Mar 24 at 8:23**
♦ Post Closed

*asked Mar 22 at 6:03*
1 program for windows in c++ [closed] (1)
**not a real question – Mar 22 at 6:11**
♦ Post Closed, Post Reopened, Post Closed

*asked Mar 14 at 9:36*
0 Accept-rate in stackoverflow [closed]
low quality – Mar 14 at 9:39
**off topic; belongs on Meta Stack Overflow – Mar 14 at 9:40**
♦ Post Closed, Post Locked, Post Migrated

*asked Mar 14 at 9:15*
-1 Why do other files open when I click on a compile-time error in Visual Studio?
**not a real question – Mar 14 at 10:25**

*asked Mar 14 at 5:36*
1 antivirus escaping from browser [closed]
**off topic; belongs on Server Fault – Mar 14 at 5:39

off topic; belongs on Super User – Mar 14 at 5:39

off topic; belongs on Super User – Mar 14 at 5:40**
♦ Post Closed, Post Migrated, Post Locked

*asked Mar 2 at 5:05*
0 silverlight in blend (2)
low quality – Mar 2 at 5:10

*asked Feb 23 at 8:30*
0 silverlightapp in vs2008 [closed]
**Duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/5087807/… – Feb 23 at 8:32**
♦ Post Closed, Edit Body, Added Comment

---

I would strongly suggest, if you wish to participate at StackOverflow, you review the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and read up on [how to ask good questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20do%20I%20ask%20good%20questions)  And, oh look!  You have some free time to do that.

Comment: Does posting questions that get migrated actually build one's "negative rep" towards banning? Talk about harsh punishment for mistakes!

Comment: @MPelletier: When the site is being flooded by lots *and lots* of users who consistently drop lousy, off-topic poorly-formatted-and-asked questions, who show *no desire* to stop being lazy and/or incompetent, who show by their very actions that they **do not care**... yes.  The worry is that they will begin to crowd out the people who do care by the sheer weight of their dreck.

Comment: I hear you, that's sensible. I'm wondering if there is some interim step, some warning sent to the user as to the behaviour you describe being harmful, before the banhammer comes down. Is there?

Comment: @MPelletier: There usually is.  But JA owns the hizzy, so if he wants to crush someone under his thumb he can get away with it.  Can't speak if he contacted via email, but he didn't send a private message over the site.

Answer (score 5):

Your account has been suspended. Exact reason can only be given by moderator, however you can read this link for possible reasons of suspension - https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/